# The condition for choosing the type of authentication does not work

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, localauthentication

I can’t get a value about supporting any type of authentication using this code:

```
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication

struct SecurityOption: View {

    let context = LAContext()
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            if (context.biometryType == .faceID) {
                Section(header:  ){
                    }
                }
            }
            if (context.biometryType == .touchID) {
                Section(header:  ){
                    }
                }
            }
            if (context.biometryType == .none) {

            }
```

I want to display a specific section in the form depending on the type of authentication on the device, but .none is constantly triggered.
Tested on real iPhone X with iOS 13.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `NSFaceIDUsageDescription` key in your app’s `Info.plist` file in order to use biometric authentication.

Comment: I use this key, but the user does not have a request for faceid permission when opening the application